# Laravel collections: GroupBy items and use WhereIn in the view

Tags: php, laravel

I'm retrieving items from the DB and grouping them by 'MONTH':

```
$events          = DB::table('events')->get();
$events_by_month = $events->groupBy('month');
```

This returns a collection like so:

```
Collection {#186 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    "DEC" => Collection {#159 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        0 => {#166 ▼
          // attributes
        }
      ]
    },
     "JAN" => Collection {#159 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        0 => {#166 ▼
          // attributes
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm passing this to the view where I want to display the items for a given month. Can I use `whereIn` here (and which case what's the key?) or is there another/better method?

No key in `whereIn` returns error:

```
@foreach($mths->whereIn(['DEC', 'JAN']) as $mth => $events)
```

Comment: `whereIn()` requires two parameters. See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-wherein

Comment: @Blake That's understood. My question is how do I filter the collection on keys after it's been grouped, given that whereIn needs two params?

Comment: Same way you would with any other array that you wanted to loop through a specific key. `foreach($array['key'] as ... )`

Comment: @greener Do it this way `@foreach($mths['DEC'] as $mth => $events)`

Comment: @prateekkathal there are many months to cater for

Comment: Can you explain how exactly you want to run the code? You can simply put 2 `@foreach` to iterate through this....

Answer (score 2):

```
 $events_by_month=DB::table('events')->get()->groupBy('month');
```

And in the view:

```
   @foreach($events_by_month->where(['month'=>'DEC') as $month=>$events)
       {{ $month }} 

       @foreach($events as $event)
         {{ $event }} 
       @endforeach

   @endforeach
```